# Who to define the meta-function using induction prinicple?

Tags: automated-theorem-proving

I'm a beginner in Automated Theorem Proving, and I want to proof using the induction principle from the syntactic definition of propositional formulae, define the meta-function $V[\phi]$ which gives set of propositional variables of the propositional formula $\phi$.

Other problem for solving is:
 Using the induction principle from the syntactic definition of propositional formulae, dene the meta-function $L[\phi]$ which gives the length of the propositional formula $\phi$.

Comment: See also the post : [length-of-a-formula-in-propositional-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533372/length-of-a-formula-in-propositional-logic).

Comment: Thank you, @MauroALLEGRANZA! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induction definition of $V[ϕ] = \text { the set of propositional variables of the formula } ϕ$.

*(i)* If $ϕ$ is *atomic*, i.e. $ϕ := p_i$ for some propositional variable $p_i$, then : $V[ϕ] = \{ p_i \}$.

*(ii)* For $ϕ = \lnot \psi$, we have : $V[ϕ] = V[\psi]$.

*(iii)* For $ϕ = \chi \cdot \psi$, where $\cdot = \{ \to, \leftrightarrow, \land, \lor \}$, we have : $V[ϕ] = V[\chi] \cup V[\psi]$.

Comment: Thank you very much, for L it's the same or?

Comment: @Laurentiu - and *lenght* is defined as ... ?